# docker: containers in stacks within EC2 instance do not inherit dns nameserver

Tags: docker, docker-network

I have set up an EC2 instance on AWS.

Have set up my security groups properly so that the instance is able to reach the Internet, e.g.

```
ubuntu@ip-10-17-0-78:/data$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com (216.58.211.164) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dub08s01-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.211.164): icmp_seq=1 ttl=46 time=1.02 ms
64 bytes from dub08s01-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.211.164): icmp_seq=2 ttl=46 time=1.00 ms
```

However, when I exec into a container, this is not possible:

```
root@d1ca5ce50d3b:/app# ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

**update_1**: the connectivity issue has to do with containers being initiated with `docker stack deploy`, in specific stacks;

When I just start a stand-alone container, connectivity to the Internet is there:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-17-0-78:/data$ docker run -it alpine:latest /bin/ash
/ # ping www.google.gr
PING www.google.gr (209.85.203.94): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 209.85.203.94: seq=0 ttl=38 time=1.148 ms
64 bytes from 209.85.203.94: seq=1 ttl=38 time=1.071 ms
```

**update_2**: After some investigation, it turns out that:

- the stand-alone container, **does** inherit the EC2 instance's dns-nameserver;
- the containers started via `docker stack deploy` do **not**;

i.e. this is from a `docker swarm` - initiated container:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-17-0-78:~$ docker exec -it d1ca5ce50d3b bash
root@d1ca5ce50d3b:/app# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
search eu-west-1.compute.internal
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

**update_3**: Same is the problem when I start the stack with `docker-compose` instead of `docker stack deploy`; does not seem to be a `swarm` - specific issue;

**update_4**: I have explicitly added the gfile `/etc/docker/daemon.json` with the following contents:

```
{
    "dns": ["10.0.0.2", "8.8.8.8"]
}
```

ubuntu@ip-10-17-0-78:/data$ docker run busybox nslookup google.com
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.211.174

*** Can't find google.com: No answer

but lookup still fails:

Any suggestions why this might be hapenning?

Comment: Try `curl` instead of `ping`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just ran into a similar issue. I realize this is 11 months old, but its somewhat difficult to find information on this topic, so I will post information here.

My issue turned out to be that the default subnet for the docker swarm overlay network was overlapping with my vpcs subnet, so the default amazon ec2 dns server (10.0.0.2) in my case was confusing the docker daemon's ip address routing into thinking it was a swarm overlay local service (I think). Anyway, I resolved my issue by changing the default overlay subnet via my stack files networking: section and my docker daemon began resolving the 10.0.0.2 vpc dns server again.

If you put your nodes docker daemon in debug module (on linux `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, add `"debug": true` to the json), you can monitor debug output by tailing the log for the daemon on your specific system. If the daemon is running via systemd, `journalctl -u docker` will give you the logs. `-f` will follow the logs.

There I found information about the connectivity issues (docker daemon was failing to get in touch with the dns server on 10.0.0.2:54 -- the udp dns port). However, nslookup was working fine on the host OS, the `/etc/resolve.conf` looked appropriate. The problem was obvious if you used docker exec to get an interactive `/bin/sh` in one of the running services. nslookup fails for any external domain, and the docker daemon debug logs spit out more "connection refused" type messages regarding 10.0.0.2. After looking around docker support issues for dns resolution for an hour or two, I found a comment stating that the docker swarm virtual networks are assigned addresses based on some defaults, and that sometimes those defaults overlap with how you've set up your local subnets. I reasoned that if they were overlapping with regards to the dns server on my vpc, it might be trying to route the dns packets intra-swarm, instead of resolving to the vpc subnet routing.

Comment: Could you please reproduce the parts of that `networking:` section that made your docker daemon begin to resolve the `10.0.0.2` vpc dns server again? I think I am facing the exact same issue, but I find the docs on how to implement your suggestion to be inconclusive...

Comment: Digging deeper... it would appear that adding this: 
```networks:
    default:
      ipam:
        driver: default
        config:
          - subnet: '192.168.0.0/24'
```
... to the `docker-compose.yml` makes it do what's needed, but I would _love_ to see some confirmation if this is, indeed, the-right-stuff™

Comment: it turned out that was my case too. CIDRs overlapping

Answer (score 4):

A clue to a more robust solution - not requiring any [`docker-compose.yml` customisation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60002175/5110545) - can be found in the output of...

```sh
docker info
```

> ```
> Server:
>     …
>     Swarm: active
>         …
>         Default Address Pool: 10.0.0.0/8  
>         SubnetSize: 24
>         …
> ```

Then, this documentation at https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-mode/#configuring-default-address-pools:

> By default Docker Swarm uses a default address pool `10.0.0.0/8` for global scope (overlay) networks.  Every network that does not have a subnet specified will have a subnet sequentially allocated from this pool.  In some circumstances it may be desirable to use a different default IP address pool for networks.
>
> For example, ***if the default `10.0.0.0/8` range conflicts with already allocated address space in your network, then it is desirable to ensure that networks use a different range*** without requiring Swarm users to specify each subnet with the `--subnet` command.

... convinces that this would also be *the* place to avoid those kind of conflicts.

We find that the default address pool can (only) be defined at `docker swarm init` time:

```sh
$ docker swarm init --default-addr-pool <IP range in CIDR> ...
```

(The `--default-addr-pool` can be repeated to extend the pool with more ranges).

And indeed, after for example

```sh
docker swarm init --default-addr-pool 192.168.0.0/16
```

... this time - *without* [altering the `docker-compose.yml` to configure a specific, different subnet for just the default network](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60002175/5110545) - it turns out that docker now picks subnets out of this default address pool, no longer overlapping with any address in the network the docker host instance itself is in.

```sh
docker info
```

> ```
> Server:
>     Swarm: active
>         …
>         Default Address Pool: 192.168.0.0/16
>         SubnetSize: 24
>     …
> ```

```sh
docker network inspect myapp_default
```

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "Name": "myapp_default",
>         …
>         "Containers": {
>             "…": {
>                 …
>                 "IPv4Address": "192.168.1.12/24",
>             },
>             …
>         },
> …
> ```

Answer (score 0):

*[edit@2020-02-10] while I think the stuff below might still interesting, I would no longer regard it to be the best solution to the problem.  That doesn't mean it does not work, but it requires **adapting the `docker-compose.yml`** to the environment it'll be lauched in, whereas one would much rather like to properly [**prepare the environment** a `docker-compose.yml` is to be launched in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60140439/5110545) instead.*

---

**Disclaimer**: This "answer" is far less an authorised solution than it is a record of the things that made it *appear* to work for me, and how they came about.

Given:

- That an AWS EC2 docker host instance exists with a private IP-address in the `10.0.0.0/16` range;
- That has been `docker swarm init`-ialized;
- That has got an application - say `myapp` - deployed as `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml myapp`;

It can be found that:

- Docker will - for the `myapp_default` network - assign each container an IP-addresses out of the `10.0.x.0/24` private range;
  This can be deduced from the output of `docker network inspect myapp_default | less -p '10\.0(\.[0-9]+){2}'`;
- The EC2 instance itself can reach out to `10.0.0.2` (AWS-provided) for its DNS;
- DNS lookups from within docker containers however, fail - *unless* the `dockerd` daemon has been additionally configured to reach out to a public DNS server (like `dockerd --dns 8.8.8.8 ...`) - *and* the instance's security group(s) allow that kind of traffic;
  The OP already found this out too.
- Explicitly doing `dockerd -dns 10.0.0.2 ...` does not seem to help one bit;

Indeed one wonders why `dockerd` is unable to mediate DNS lookups between the private `10.0.x.0/24` range of its `myapp_default` network and the one that its EC2 host instance is in; after all, they're still two completely disconnected networks that just happen to have chosen overlapping ip-ranges, but apparently - as was already pointed out by @Josh - this is the case;

Also, given whatever limitation is at the root of this, one can't help but wonder why "docker" doesn't detect this situation automatically and then simply chooses a non-overlapping range for the `myapp_default` network instead;

It would appear we just have to explicitly remedy this ourselves; so how can we do it? How can we make "docker" choose a different range for its `myapp_default` network?

@Josh hints at an answer and together with bits and pieces of information gathered from:

- https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network
- https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2582#issuecomment-204520849
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipam
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

... I've concocted this top-level section to be added to `docker-compose.yml`:

```
networks:
    default:
        ipam:
            config:
                -
                    subnet: '192.168.0.0/24'
            driver: 'default'
```

After re-deploying `myapp`, the output of `docker network inspect myapp_default` provides the evidence that containers are no longer handed out IP-addresses out of the `10.0.x.0/24` range but from `192.168.0.0/24` instead - *and* we find that their DNS lookups now do work!

What I do *not* (yet) know is wether the above is both necessary and sufficient a solution to the problem, and not opening up some other can of worms...

Comment: see also: https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1429#issuecomment-280522121