# Unable to access AWS CloudWatch from containers on EC2 instance on private subnet

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a AWS VPC setup with three EC2 instances, where one has access to the public internet, while the other two don't. The application services (developed in node.js) are docker containerized and run across all three instances. I am in the process of moving their logs from files to AWS CloudWatch. The application uses the Winston logger, and I added winston-cloudwatch to provide the transport for CloudWatch.

```js
export const logger = new winston.createLogger({
  transports: [],
  handleExceptions: false,
  exitOnError: false
});
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  const cloudWatchConfig = {
    logGroupName: process.env.CLOUDWATCH_GROUP_NAME,
    logStreamName: process.env.SERVICE,
    awsRegion: process.env.CLOUDWATCH_REGION,
    messageFormatter: ({ level, message }) => `[${process.env.SERVICE}:${level}] : ${message}`
  }
  logger.add(new WinstonCloudWatch(cloudWatchConfig))
}
```

The containers running on the EC2 instance with public internet access are sending the logs to CloudWatch; no issues there. However, the ones running on an instance on the private subnet are not able to. The first problem was gaining access to the CloudWatch server from that EC2 instance, and for that I setup a VPC Interface EndPoint on the private subnet for the service com.amazonaws.ca-central-1.logs. After that I can access CloudWatch from the instance, i.e., I can access CloudWatch using command line instructions such as:

```
$ aws logs describe-log-groups --log-group-name my-app-logs
```

etc. I can also create logs using the "put-log-events" sub-command.

However, from within the containers on this instance I still cannot connect to CloudWatch. This is the error I am getting:

> UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `logs.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the` ca-central-1' region.
> at Request.ENOTFOUND_ERROR (/users-svc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:530:46)
> at Request.callListeners (/users-svc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
> at Request.emit (/users-svc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
> at Request.emit (/users-svc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
> at error (/users-svc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:362:22)
> at ClientRequest. (/users-svc/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/http/node.js:99:9)
> at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:400:28)
> at ClientRequest.emit (domain.js:470:12)
> at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:475:9)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28) {   code: 'UnknownEndpoint',   region: 'ca-central-1',   hostname: 'logs.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com',
> retryable: true,   originalError: Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN
> logs.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com
> at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:69:26) {
> errno: -3001,
> code: 'NetworkingError',
> syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
> hostname: 'logs.ca-central-1.amazonaws.com',
> region: 'ca-central-1',
> retryable: true,
> time: 2021-08-17T16:30:35.796Z   },   time: 2021-08-17T16:30:35.796Z }

So, the application service in the container is not able to reach the CloudWatch host.

I am new to AWS, so this could be due to a trivial omission. However, I suspect that the problem is with the container not able to find this CloudWatch Interface EndPoint on the private subnet, which in turn is likely because it cannot resolve the hostname to IP address. While the containers connect with each other over an overlay network, how should they connect to this EndPoint? The Interface EndPoint gets an IP address assigned on the private subnet, which allows instances to connect to AWS services (CloudWatch, in this case) over AWS' PrivateLink. Since I can connect to CloudWatch from this instance on the private subnet, the instance can resolve the hostname to IP address. How do I make the containers on this instance do the same? The containers on the instance with access to the public internet are using Google's DNS servers 8.8.8.8 and 9.9.9.9 so they are able to resolve the CloudWatch's hostname's public IP address. The containers on the instance on the private subnet must need some way to resolve CloudWatch hostname's IP address on the private subnet.

Incidentally, I have seen references to awslogs driver and CloudWatch agent in enabling logging from containers, but I think those provide alternative ways of getting the logs from containers to CloudWatch; I should be able do so without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this problem resulted from a conflict in the subnet address space allocated to the private subnet in my VPC and the way docker swarm creates its subnet space by default. This is the stackoverflow source that answered my inquiry[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51404544/docker-containers-in-stacks-within-ec2-instance-do-not-inherit-dns-nameserver), and in particular the first answer posted by user cueedee, not his second. I tried the second method first, which is to add the following to docker-compose-yml:

```
networks:
    default:
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: '192.168.0.0/24'
            driver: 'default'
```

This did not work: docker stack deploy did not update the address space as expressed by this directive. After this, I tried to force the update like this:

> $ docker swarm init --default-addr-pool 192.168.0.0/16
> --force-new-cluster

Still, docker swarm did not update its subnet address space. Finally, I did what was suggested by cueedee in his first answer, i.e., to create the swarm anew:

> $ docker swarm init --default-addr-pool 192.168.0.0/16

This gave me the desired result, as I can verify with:

$ docker info

```
 Swarm: active
  NodeID: 
  Is Manager: true
  ClusterID: 
  Managers: 3
  Nodes: 3
  Default Address Pool: 192.168.0.0/16  
  SubnetSize: 24
```

Redeploying the application with the original docker-compose.yml removed the problem I was facing: Containers on the private subnet are now able to send logs to CloudWatch.